# Return varchars containing numbers in numerical order

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains varchars with numbers in them such as "03-011A" or "03.011A" or "03-011" or "03.011" etc...
However, standard methods of numerical order seem ineffective and they still return unordered, I've checked for solutions but alas, I have found no cure.

Got any ideas?

Comment: You have a problem with your database (design) if it contains "numers" in that way. I advise converting all the text into a standard (preferably not text) format

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt have this kind of inconsistencies in your database. Choose a format and stick to it.

However you could use ie NumericOnly()  ( http://venerableagents.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/mysql-numeric-functions/ ) in your `ORDER BY` statement or some other sort of RegEx Operation

Comment: I have no alternative as this is to my clients specifications, it'd take alot of code rework to seperate the two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the "Number-Field" with Order like:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field=test **ORDER BY number_field ASC**

Otherwise you can try to order that over PHP (With arrays).

Comment: This does not work in a situation where varchars are in use, that order by example merely works on integers.

Comment: Than you must use that over PHP. Use the Query-Result on a variable and sort this Array.

Comment: MySQL is very powerful i dont think php is a good alternative for this!